# How to remove local server from react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

How to remove local server from react project started by using `npx create-react-app my-app`. I want my project not run when we run `npm start` command. I want to use my react project like simple HTML files.

Comment: Have you tried “npm run build”?

Comment: @JBallin No I did not. What does it do?

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen It compiles your code for production, then you can host it

Comment: Yash is correct. It will build the app as static files in the build folder. Can you clarify why you want to do this?

Comment: @JBallin I am creating an app using reactjs (frontend) and nodej (backend). I have created my frontend but it runs on port 3000 with local server. I want it to run on same port as node js on node js server not its local server.

Comment: Try something like this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#other-solutions

Comment: @JBallin It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build a static app in create-react-app, you should use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.

To then serve the build output in an existing server, you can do something like:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(9000);
```

More info in create-react-app [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#other-solutions).

Answer (score 0):

`npm start` is a script defined (by default), in your `package.json`. If you want it to not run anything or a different command, you can simply edit or delete it. The `create-react-app` does use `webpack` to build your app, so you'll still need a build command to generate the javascript files you can put in your html file.